# Difference between ‘satisfy with’ and ‘content to’

Tags: word-usage

It seems that ‘satisfy’ is used with ‘with’ and ‘content’ is used with ‘to’. But I’m confused about the usage.

Is there any difference between the meening? or Can I just use both of them anytime?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They're synonyms although content means `satisfy in a limited way`.

**Satisfied:** Emotional or physical pleased and happy with the result. Might something has happened in the way that you want, or because you have got what you want.

**Content:** Happy with status quo(state of a situation as it is). Satisfied with things as they are.

Answer (score 1):

Satisfied and content are usually treated as synonyms, although satisfied is more specific, content more general.

You can be satisfied or content with something, you can be satisfied or content with doing something, and you can be content doing something or content to do something:

1. I am satisfied with the outcome of our meeting.
2. I am content with the outcome of our meeting.
3. I am satisfied with going to the pool once a week.
4. I am content with going to the pool once a week.
5. I am content going to the pool once a week.
6. I am content to go to the pool once a week.

The meaning of 3, 4, 5, & 6 is subtly different.

3 - going once a week meets my need

4 - going once a week is enough for me (though I may like to go often)

5 - going once a week makes me happy

6 - I'm happy to go once a week (though I may prefer to go less often)